# Get total count of mentions from a twitter api response

Tags: php, arrays, twitter, count

I am using the basic search twitter api, I would like to get the total count of a specific word mentioned in the response. This is what my api call looks like -

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";

// Keyword to search
$getfield = '?q=elrond&count=20';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);

if(array_key_exists("errors", $string)) {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($string);
echo "</pre>";

foreach($string as $array){
    $i++;
}

echo $i;
```

When I echo $i I get a count of 2, but if I look at the actual response their is over 100 mentions of the keyword. What method would I use to count the number of times the keyword is in the response?

Here is an example response I get -

```
[1] => Array
            (
                [created_at] => Tue Aug 11 16:04:39 +0000 2020
                [id] => 1293216771244261381
                [id_str] => 1293216771244261381
                [text] => @Meter_IO @ElrondNetwork You know just the right partnership, with elrond network, you are certainly in for something big. 
                [truncated] => 
                [entities]
```

I would be searching the [text] field to get the count

Comment: I'm seeing some syntax problems now, but maybe it's because your code example is messed up. Please fix your code / indentation and maybe we'll be able to help you

Comment: Yes its an example but could you be a gent and tell me what you're seeing wrong?

Comment: For instance, close your `if` statements with a `}`. And close your strings with `";`

Comment: Thanks for the input, should be better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some syntax errors here and are missing a definition of `i`, but the fundamental issue is that you're trying to count the wrong thing.

If you `print_r($string)` at the end of your code, you will see that it is returning an array containing 2 items - `[statuses] => Array` and `[search_metadata] => Array`. So 2 is the correct output from your script as written.

What you could do instead, is to count the statuses array itself.

```php
foreach($string["statuses"] as $array){
    $i++;
}
```

The other thing you could do is to look at the `[search_metadata]` array, which contains the count of the results:

```php
   [search_metadata] => Array
        (
            [completed_in] => 0.161
            [max_id] => 1293225170983772160
            [max_id_str] => 1293225170983772160
            [next_results] => ?max_id=1293218662854402059&q=elrond&count=20&include_entities=1
            [query] => elrond
            [refresh_url] => ?since_id=1293225170983772160&q=elrond&include_entities=1
            [count] => 20
            [since_id] => 0
            [since_id_str] => 0
        )
```

Although, both of these actually return the number of Tweets, which match the number you requested `count=20`... so if you want to count the keywords, you'll have to decide which fields(s) in each response Tweet you want to count them from, and then iterate over those entries in each string.

Comment: Thank you for the help